# UpperCase letter in Preferences API

Tags: java, preferences

In the Preferences API provided by JDK. It appears that
each upper case letter written into the windows registry by the API is
preceded by a '/' character.
e.g if the Node name is TestNode it will appear as Test/Node.How can i overcome this?

```
Preferences pre = Preferences.userRoot();
Preferences child = pre.node("TestNode");
```

It will be created as Test/Node in registry,which causes problem in readability and locating the node in the tree,if many nodes are present having Uppercase names.

Comment: Why, necessarily, is this a bad thing?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score -2):

Why dont you just remove that?

```
String result = "Test/Node".replaceAll("/", "");
```

Comment: I'm not certain that it's this simple.

Comment: The Windows registry adds the "/" while creating the node.